# Excel recursive procedure to create an array

Tags: arrays, excel, recursion, multidimensional-array, vba

I have the following data:

[image: data]

And my goal is to do this:

- Recursive sub that will create an array filled with the materials.
- Everytime a material is set as "Crafted", the array will add another sub-material at the same dimension adding a ".1". Example: If we look at bow, it's crafted, so the array would look like this when finished: Material: array(0,0,0) = Wood, Quantity: array(0,0,1) = 2, Level: array(0,0,2) = 1.
- But then, the sublevel would become: Material: array(0,1,0) = Branch, Quantity: array(0,1,1) = 2, Level: array(0,1,2) = 1.1
- And since Branch is crafted: Material: array(0,2,0) = Tree, Quantity: array(0,2,1) = 1, Level: array(0,2,2) = 1.1.1.
- And then: Material: array(0,3,0) = Leaf, Quantity: array(0,3,1) = 9, Level: array(0,3,2) = 1.2.
- It would then look for the next material "Rope" and go on: Material: array(1,0,0) = Rope, Quantity: array(1,0,1) = 1, Level: array(1,0,2) = 1, Material: array(1,1,0) = Web, Quantity: array(1,1,1) = 10, Level: array(1,1,2) = 2.1 and so on.

My main problem is that I am not that familiar with recursive code and my logic seems wrong, so I figured I would look for help and ask here how it could be done.

Here is my code so far, it's partially working:

```
Sub Look(ByRef arrayMaterials)

Dim item

    With ActiveSheet
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    With ActiveSheet
        lastColumn = .Cells(j + 2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With

For i = 0 To lastRow
    For y = 0 To lastColumn
        item = Cells(i + 2, 1).Value
        If Cells(i + 1, y + 1).Value = item And Cells(i + 1, y + 1).Value <> "Item" Then
            arrayMaterials = ReDimPreserve(arrayMaterials, i, i, y)
            arrayMaterials(i - 1, i - 1, y - 2) = Cells(i + 1, y + 1).Value
            arrayMaterials(i - 1, i - 1, y - 1) = Cells(i + 1, y + 2).Value
            level = level & CInt(Right(Cells(1, y + 3), 2))
            arrayMaterials(i - 1, i - 1, y) = level
            level = CInt(Right(Cells(1, y + 3), 2))
                If Cells(i + 1, y + 1).Value <> "Resource" Then
                    level = level & "."
                    Look (arrayMaterials)
                End If
        End If
    Next
Next

Look (arrayMaterials)

End Sub
```

Called by:

```
Sub CallLook()
    Dim arrayMaterials(1, 1, 1)
    Look (arrayMaterials)
End Sub
```

Also (to get rid of the Preserve limitation of the last dimension):

```
Public Function ReDimPreserve(aArrayToPreserve, nNewFirstUBound, nNewSecondUBound, nNewLastUBound)
    ReDimPreserve = False
    'check if its in array first
    If IsArray(aArrayToPreserve) Then
        'create new array
        ReDim aPreservedArray(nNewFirstUBound, nNewSecondUBound, nNewLastUBound)
        'get old lBound/uBound
        nOldFirstUBound = UBound(aArrayToPreserve, 1)
        nOldSecondUBound = UBound(aArrayToPreserve, 2)
        nOldLastUBound = UBound(aArrayToPreserve, 3)
        'loop through first
        For nFirst = LBound(aArrayToPreserve, 1) To nNewFirstUBound
            For nSecond = LBound(aArrayToPreserve, 2) To nNewSecondUBound
                For nLast = LBound(aArrayToPreserve, 3) To nNewLastUBound
                    'if its in range, then append to new array the same way
                    If nOldFirstUBound >= nFirst And nOldSecondUBound >= nSecond And nOldLastUBound >= nLast Then
                        aPreservedArray(nFirst, nSecond, nLast) = aArrayToPreserve(nFirst, nSecond, nLast)
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        Next
        'return the array redimmed
        If IsArray(aPreservedArray) Then ReDimPreserve = aPreservedArray
    End If
End Function
```

The variable "level" is declared globally.

Can you help me out figure what's not working with this code please?

I think I might have some of the indexes (i and y) wrong. I am not that experienced with coding either.

All the help is appreciated.

EDIT: As requested in the comments, here is the output of both the arry and Excel:

Array:

```
(0,0,0) = Wood, 2, 1
(0,1,0) = Branch, 2, 1.1
(0,1,1) = Tree, 1, 1.1.1
(0,2,0) = Leaf, 9, 1.2
(1,0,0) = Rope, 1, 2
(1,1,0) = Web, 10, 2.1
(1,1,1) = Spider, 5, 2.1.1
(2,0,0) = Crystal, 3, 3
(3,0,0) = Shard, 8, 4
(4,0,0) = Plumes, 1, 5
(4,1,0) = Bird, 1, 5.1
```

Excel (each entry is a row, the item and quantity are on the same column, due to restrictions, I cannot add a column):

```
Bow (is already on the other sheet, no need to add it, "-" are indents)
-Wood - 2
--Branch - 4 (2 Wood, so 4 Branches)
---Tree - 4
--Leaf - 18
-Rope - 1
--Web - 10
---Spider - 50
-Crystal - 3
-Shard - 8
-Plumes - 1
--Birds - 1
```

I hope it gives you a better idea of what I need.

EDIT: 2015-07-13 - Added the new code as per Tony Dallimore's suggestions:

Please note that this is not the finished product, I still have to pass the item I want the materials for and code the output, I wanted to make sure I would understand everything up to that point before going further.

On my data sheet I got a button that calls sFilltypes.

```
Public Type tComponent   RowMaterial As Long   Quantity As Long End Type

Public Type tMaterial   Name As String   Crafted As Boolean   Used As Boolean   Component() As tComponent End Type

Sub sFillTypes()

Dim count
Dim Materials() As tMaterial

With ActiveSheet
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

ReDim Materials(1 To lastRow - 1)

For i = 2 To lastRow
    count = 0
    With ActiveSheet
        lastColumn = .Cells(i, .Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            For k = 1 To lastColumn
            If Left(Cells(1, k), 8) = "Material" And Cells(1, k).Value <> "" Then
                count = count + 1
            End If
        Next
    End With
    ReDim Materials(i - 1).Component(1 To 1)
    If UBound(Materials(i - 1).Component, 1) <= count Then
        ReDim Materials(i - 1).Component(1 To count)
    Else
        Erase Materials(i - 1).Component
    End If
    Materials(i - 1).Name = Cells(i, 1).Value
        If Cells(i, 2).Value = "Crafted" Then
            Materials(i - 1).Crafted = "True"
        Else
            Materials(i - 1).Crafted = "False"
        End If
    For y = 1 To lastColumn + 1
        If InStr(Cells(1, y).Value, "Material") Then
            For Z = 1 To lastRow
                If Cells(i, y).Value = Cells(Z, 1).Value Then
                    Materials(i - 1).Component(Right(Cells(1, y), 2)).RowMaterial = Z
                    Materials(i - 1).Component(Right(Cells(1, y), 2)).Quantity = Cells(i, y + 1)
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do but I doubt that using multidimensional arrays is the way to go. It might make more sense to have something like a variant array whose values are variant arrays (whose values can be variant arrays, etc.) or perhaps a dictionary of dictionaries or a collection of collections.

Comment: I'll take the array afterward to do an output like this in Excel cells: Bow, insert a row, Wood 2, insert a row, Branch 4, insert a row, Tree 4...

Comment: I didn't look too much into the details of the code, but you'll need to control how recursion increments or decrements arrayMaterials from one call to the next, and make sure you have closure (lower or upper bounds for stopping the process)

Comment: Is the goal of this the array or some subsequent output based on it?  There might be a better way to do this if the output is something other than the array.  Remember that Excel is a very robust 2d array so you can often get output by processing the data in the `Worksheet` using `Insert` (among other functions) to move things around.  If output is the goal, you will get better answers if you include expected/desired output.

Comment: Recursion is a powerful technique that is very useful for some problems.  But your objective should be to do something of benefit to your organisation and not to do that something in a particular way.

Comment: I do not understand: "Bow, insert a row, Wood 2, insert a row, ..." but it seems you want to create a new worksheet with the source information arranged differently.  If you explained the format of that new worksheet, I believe I (and perhaps others) would better understand how you are trying to rearrange your source data.

Comment: Greetings again, thanks for all the comments and the notes, I'll try to answer everyone, but first, as per Tony Dallimore's request I added an edit to the output format I would like in the array, and then Excel. To paul bica: I am not that used in programming, and it's why I am asking help for the "logic". To Byron Wall: I need to keep the array as well after the ouput. As I said, I'll provide the output. To Tony Dallymore: The crafted item can contain other crafted and so on (n times), it's why I do it recursively, there could also be n materials as well. Let me know if I missed something.

Comment: It is now 3 days since I posted an updated version of sFillTypes.  You are visiting Stack Overflow but have not acknowledged my code.  Have you lost interest in this question or is there a problem?

Comment: Greetings, sorry for the lack of updates, I have just been busy with real life issues. I will accept your code as an answer but I still have to understand parts of it, if I have further questions, I'll let you know. Thanks a lot for all the help so far, this sent me in the right direction.

Comment: I have tried to explain them all but my macro contains a lot of ideas that can be difficult to grasp.  Like so many such ideas, once you have grasped them, you do not understand why you had a problem..I think learning to programming is like learning to drive. During your first lesson, you are told you are expected to simultaneously turn a wheel, work three pedals and a gear stick, look in three mirrors while continually watching the road ahead. You **know** you will never be able to do all that but some how, a few weeks later, you are. Take it slowly and come back with questions as necessary..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a limit of 30,000 characters per answer which I must be close to.  There is also value in keeping the first answer separate from the follow on answer(s).

There are some problems with your routine which needed correction. I have gone a little OTT and have made changes for reasons of good practice. I have also added a routine that displays Materials as a check that it is correct. Study my code and try to determine why I have made the changes I have.  Come back with questions as necessary.

```
Option Explicit

Public Type tComponent
  RowMaterial As Long
  Quantity As Long
End Type

Public Type tMaterial
  Name As String
  Crafted As Boolean
  Used As Boolean
  Component() As tComponent
End Type
Sub sFillTypes()

  ' Constants have two major benefits:
  '  * Instead of literals your code contains meaningful names making your
  '    code easier to read.
  '  * If the value changes, one amendment here fixes the code. For example,
  '    suppose a new column is added on the left. Looking through the code
  '    deciding which 2s, 3s and 4s are to be changed to 3s, 4s and 5s is
  '    nightmare.
  ' Variable names should be meaningful.  Reading code full of Ks, Xs and Ys
  ' is difficult because the reader has to remember what they are. My system
  ' is to use a sequence of words or abbreviations. The first word says what
  ' I am using the variable for: Col=column number, Row=row number, etc.
  ' Each additional word reduces the scope until I have a unique name. I do
  ' not know the name of your worksheet so I have used Sht as the second word
  ' of variables that relate to the worksheet. Crnt (=current), First and Last
  ' are common words in my names. I can look at routines I wrote 10 years ago
  ' and immediately know what all the variables are which is a real help when
  ' trying to update them.  If you do not like my system, develop your own.

  Const ColShtItem As Long = 1
  Const ColShtType As Long = 2
  Const ColShtMatFirst As Long = 3
  Const RowShtDataFirst As Long = 2

  Dim ColShtCrnt As Long
  Dim ColShtLast As Long
  Dim ColShtMatLast As Long
  Dim ColShtUsed As Long
  Dim Found As Boolean
  Dim InxComp As Long
  Dim Materials() As tMaterial
  Dim RowShtCrnt As Long
  Dim RowShtItem As Long
  Dim RowShtLast As Long
  Dim ValuesSht As Variant

  With ActiveSheet

    ' Cell.End is a convenient way of finding the last used cell in a row or column.
    ' It is probably a reliable way of finding the last row of your worksheet but you
    ' are relying on row 1 having a complete set of headers to determine the last column
    ' which makes me uncomfortable.
    RowShtLast = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    ColShtLast = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column

    ' I do not know what you are doing with Count but this code cannot be at the top.  Each
    ' row will have its own number of materials

    ' * This statements loads the values of the range to ValuesSht as an array.
    ' * I have loaded the first data row to the last row because I do not want the
    '   header row. I have loaded column 1 to last column plus 1 because I want an extra,
    '   blank column on the left.
    ' * ValuesSht will become a 2D array with the first dimension being for rows and the
    '   second for columns.
    ' * The top left cell of ValuesSht will always be (1,1) even if the range does not
    '   start in cell (1,1).

    ValuesSht = .Range(Cells(RowShtDataFirst, 1), .Cells(RowShtLast, ColShtLast + 1))

  End With

  ReDim Materials(1 To UBound(ValuesSht, 1))

  ' I will use the RowSht variables for ValuesSht even though the worksheet and array
  ' rows do not match because I have finished with the worksheet.  The worksheet and
  ' array columns match so I will use the ColSht variables for both.
  ' I will also use the RowSht variables for Materials since the rows match.

  ColShtUsed = ColShtLast + 1      ' I load an extra column to hold used values

  For RowShtCrnt = 1 To UBound(ValuesSht, 1)

    ' Copy across the non-repeating values
    Materials(RowShtCrnt).Name = Trim(ValuesSht(RowShtCrnt, ColShtItem))
    Select Case LCase(Trim(ValuesSht(RowShtCrnt, ColShtType)))
      Case "crafted"
        Materials(RowShtCrnt).Crafted = True
      Case "resource"
        Materials(RowShtCrnt).Crafted = False
      Case Else
        ' Do not assume the worksheet is perfect.
        Call MsgBox("Cell B" & RowShtCrnt + RowShtDataFirst - 1 & _
                    " does nor contain ""Crafted"" or ""Resource""", vbOKOnly)
        Exit Sub
    End Select
    ' If materials are not always below the item that uses them, this block
    ' will have to be in its own loop after the rest of Materials has been created
    If ValuesSht(RowShtCrnt, ColShtUsed) = "U" Then
      Materials(RowShtCrnt).Used = True
    Else
      Materials(RowShtCrnt).Used = False
    End If

    If Materials(RowShtCrnt).Crafted Then

      ' Replace material names in columns ColShtMatFirst, ColShtMatFirst+2 and so on
      ' with the number of the row for the material.

      ' Loop over all possible material columns
      For ColShtCrnt = ColShtMatFirst To ColShtLast - 1 Step 2
        If Trim(ValuesSht(RowShtCrnt, ColShtCrnt)) = "" Then
          ColShtMatLast = ColShtCrnt - 2
          Exit For
        End If

        ' Look down the remainder of ValuesSht for this material.
        ' This relies on used materials always being below the material they are
        ' used to make.  This is a easy way of (1) preventing loops and (2) ensuring
        ' the used column is ready when required.  If materials are not in this
        ' sequence, you will need a more sophisticated method of detecting loops such
        ' as: Material1 used to make Material2, Material2 used to make Material3 and
        ' Material3 used to make Material1.
        Found = False
        For RowShtItem = RowShtCrnt + 1 To UBound(ValuesSht, 1)
          If Trim(ValuesSht(RowShtItem, ColShtItem)) = _
             Trim(ValuesSht(RowShtCrnt, ColShtCrnt)) Then
            ValuesSht(RowShtCrnt, ColShtCrnt) = RowShtItem
            Found = True
            Exit For
          End If
        Next RowShtItem
        If Not Found Then
          Call MsgBox("I cannot find the material in cell " & _
                      ColNumToCode(ColShtCrnt) & RowShtCrnt + RowShtDataFirst - 1 & _
                      " (" & ValuesSht(RowShtCrnt, ColShtCrnt) & ") defined on rows " & _
                      RowShtCrnt + 2 & " to " & UBound(ValuesSht, 1) + 1, vbOKOnly)
          Exit Sub
        End If
        ValuesSht(RowShtItem, ColShtUsed) = "U"  ' Record this item used
      Next ColShtCrnt

      ' For the current row, the material names in columns ColShtMatFirst, ColShtMatFirst+2
      ' and so on have been replaced by row numbers.  ColShtMatLast has been set as
      ' appropriate for this row.

      ' Size Components as required for this material and move component detals for ValuesSht
      ReDim Materials(RowShtCrnt).Component(1 To (ColShtMatLast - ColShtMatFirst) / 2 + 1)
      InxComp = 1
      For ColShtCrnt = ColShtMatFirst To ColShtMatLast Step 2
        Materials(RowShtCrnt).Component(InxComp).RowMaterial = ValuesSht(RowShtCrnt, ColShtCrnt)
        Materials(RowShtCrnt).Component(InxComp).Quantity = ValuesSht(RowShtCrnt, ColShtCrnt + 1)
        InxComp = InxComp + 1
      Next

    End If ' Materials(RowShtCrnt).Crafted

  Next RowShtCrnt

  ' Delete or comment out this line when you are satified the above code is correct.
  Call ListMaterials(Materials)



End Sub
Sub ListMaterials(ByRef Materials() As tMaterial)

  ' Debug.Print is very useful when debugging code.  The only downside is that the
  ' Immediate Window will only hold 200 or so lines.  After that, line at the top
  ' get lost.  If I have or expect too many lines for the Immediate Window, I use
  ' a text file.

  Dim InxComp As Long
  Dim InxMat As Long
  Dim InxMatUsed As Long
  Dim LenMatNameMax As Long
  Dim Name As String
  Dim NumCompMax As Long

  ' Determine maximum length of a material name and the maximum number of
  ' components so the output can be formatted nicely.
  LenMatNameMax = 0
  NumCompMax = 0

  For InxMat = LBound(Materials) To UBound(Materials)
    If LenMatNameMax < Len(Materials(InxMat).Name) Then
      LenMatNameMax = Len(Materials(InxMat).Name)
    End If
    If Materials(InxMat).Crafted Then
      If NumCompMax < UBound(Materials(InxMat).Component) Then
        NumCompMax = UBound(Materials(InxMat).Component)
      End If
    End If
  Next InxMat

  ' List Materials and their components

  ' Output header line
  Debug.Print Left("Name" & Space(LenMatNameMax), LenMatNameMax) & " T U |";
  For InxComp = 1 To NumCompMax
    Debug.Print Left("Material" & Space(LenMatNameMax), LenMatNameMax) & " Qty|";
  Next
  Debug.Print

  ' Output materials
  For InxMat = LBound(Materials) To UBound(Materials)
    Debug.Print Left(Materials(InxMat).Name & Space(LenMatNameMax), LenMatNameMax + 1) & _
                IIf(Materials(InxMat).Crafted, "C ", "R ") & _
                IIf(Materials(InxMat).Used, "Y ", "  ") & "|";
    If Materials(InxMat).Crafted Then
      For InxComp = 1 To UBound(Materials(InxMat).Component)
        Name = Materials(Materials(InxMat).Component(InxComp).RowMaterial).Name
        Debug.Print Left(Name & Space(LenMatNameMax), LenMatNameMax + 1) & _
                    Right("   " & Materials(InxMat).Component(InxComp).Quantity, 3) & "|";
      Next
    End If
    Debug.Print
  Next InxMat

End Sub
Function ColNumToCode(ByVal ColNum As Long) As String

  ' Last updated 3 Feb 12.  Adapted to handle three character codes.

  Dim ColCode As String
  Dim PartNum As Long

  If ColNum = 0 Then
    ColNumToCode = "0"
  Else
    ColCode = ""
    Do While ColNum > 0
      PartNum = (ColNum - 1) Mod 26
      ColCode = Chr(65 + PartNum) & ColCode
      ColNum = (ColNum - PartNum - 1) \ 26
    Loop
  End If

  ColNumToCode = ColCode

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Bow (is already on the other sheet, ...

I doubt this is a good idea.

With your demonstration data, “bow” is the only material that is not a component of something else.  Will this be true of your real data?  How will you know which elements of the array relate to which row in the worksheet?

Perhaps more importantly, the data required for the next step of processing is spread across two sources.  You may be saving space (the array will be a little smaller) but this makes your code more complex and slower.  I remember when space was tight (the first commercial computer for which I was a programmer had between 45 and 1000Kb † of memory for the operating system and 16 users) and we would accept increased complexity and slower runtime as a necessary price for fitting our programs into the memory available.  You do not have to make that sacrifice.  A simple program is quicker to write, easier to maintain and more reliable so start simple.

† I am not joking; I really do mean the maximum memory was 1Mb.

---

My understanding is you wish to transfer the data within the worksheet to memory so it is arranged more conveniently for processing.  I find it difficult to see how your array could be convenient for anything.  There is also the complexity of the processing necessary to create it.  How long did you spend writing `ReDimPreserve`?

Please consider the following alternative structures.

---

```
  |   1   |     2  | 3| 4| 5| 6| 7| 8| 9|10|11|12|
--|-------|--------|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|
 1|Bow    |Crafted | 2| 2| 3| 1| 5| 3|10| 8| 6| 1|
 2|Wood   |Crafted | 4| 2|12| 9|
 3|Rope   |Crafted | 8|10|
 4|Branch |Crafted |13| 1|
 5|Crystal|Resource|
 6|Plumes |Crafted | 7| 1|
 7|Bird   |Resource|
 8|Web    |Crafted |11| 5|
 9|String |Resource|
10|Shard  |Resource|
11|Spider |Resource|
12|Leaf   |Resource|
13|Tree   |Resource|
```

This is called a ragged array because each row is a different length.  This is logically the same as the worksheet.  The values in columns 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 and 12 are unchanged.  The words in columns 3, 5, 7, 9 and 11 have been replaced by row numbers.  For example: “Wood” has been replaced by “2” and “Rope” has been replaced by “3” where “2” and “3” are the rows holding details of Wood and Rope.  (I created this table by hand but I am sure you can see the idea even if there are mistakes.

I hope you can see that getting from Bow to each of its components (Wood, Rope, Crystal, Shard and Plumes), and from Wood to its components (Branch and Leaf), would not be difficult.  I also hope you can see it would be no major problems in converting the worksheet to this array.

Don’t worry at this stage how you create a ragged array rather than a square or cube array.  At this stage I want you to think about data structures.  Get the correct data structure and the program structure will be easy.  With the wrong data structure, the program will be from difficult to impossible to code.

---

The structure above is simple but not self-documenting.  Is column 7 a material or a quantity?  For this problem, it may not be important for the structure to be self-documenting but for more complex problems it will be.

Long, String, Double and Boolean are intrinsic data types which come with the programming language.  Often these intrinsic data types are enough but sometimes they are not.  All the general purpose languages I know have some means of building more complex data types from these simple data types.  Most languages call these complex data types “structures” but VBA calls them “user types”.  Consider:

```
Type tComponent
  RowMaterial As Long
  Quantity As Long
End Type

Type tMaterial
  Name As String
  Crafted As Boolean
  Component() As tComponent
End Type
```

The statements `Type xxx` to `End Type` define a user type.  I always seem to want to use the same name for a type and a variable.  One of my conventions is to have a leading “t” for a type name.

I first define a component of a crafted material.  A component corresponds to columns (3,4), (5,6) and so on.  I then define a material which has a name, a Boolean to record crafted or resource and an array of components.  If a material is a resource, `Crafted` will be `False` and `Component` will not be used.  If a material is crafted, `Crafted` will be `True` and `Component` will be `ReDimed` as appropriate and value stored.

Consider how `Type` tMaterial relates to a worksheet row.  Column 1 contains a name and column 2 contains “Crafted” or “Resource”.  I have replaced column 2 with a Boolean variable but that is just a different way of encoding the same information.  `Type` tComponent, which contains a row number identifying the component and a quantity, matches the column pairs (3, 4), (5, 6) and so on.  The big difference is tMaterial is self-documenting.  If you return to these macros in six or twelve months which of these two approaches will be easier to understand?  I believe that approach 2 will be the easier.  If a macro, or any other program, is to be maintained to meet changing requirements, making life easy for the maintenance programmer is a very important consideration; after all, you might be that maintenance programmer.

The following code shows how these user types would be used:

```
Sub ShowConcept()

  Dim Materials() As tMaterial

  ReDim Materials(1 To 13)

  Materials(1).Name = "Bow"
  Materials(1).Crafted = True
  ReDim Materials(1).Components(1 To 5)
  Materials(1).Components(1).RowMaterial = 2
  Materials(1).Components(1).Quantity = 2
  Materials(1).Components(2).RowMaterial = 3
  Materials(1).Components(2).Quantity = 1
  Materials(1).Components(3).RowMaterial = 5
  Materials(1).Components(3).Quantity = 3
  '  : : :
  Materials(2).Name = "Wood"
  Materials(2).Crafted = True
  ReDim Materials(2).Components(1 To 2)
  Materials(2).Components(1).RowMaterial = 4
  Materials(2).Components(1).Quantity = 2
  Materials(2).Components(2).RowMaterial = 12
  Materials(2).Components(2).Quantity = 8
  '  : : :

End Sub
```

---

The two data structures above are logically the same; they just demonstrate two methods of achieving the same effect.  I have not mentally tested the data structure yet although it feels about right.  The next step is to “use” this structure.  It may be necessary to modify or even discard my first attempt at an appropriate data structure for your problem but I hope not.

---

You need three macros.  You need one macro to create the array from the original worksheet and another to create the new worksheet from the array.  With your demonstration data there is only one material that is not a component of another.  You could create a macro that output the components of row 1 of the array (row 2 of the worksheet).  But your real data might have several such “unused” materials and, I assume, you would wish all of them to be output to the new worksheet.  You need a control macro that calls the array-creating macro and then calls the output macro for each unused material.

How does the macro recognise an unused material?  With the worksheet and the current array, it is not immediately obvious which materials are unused.  Is the material described by row 9, for example, used?  I would need to look at all the other rows.  Only if no other row used row 9’s material would it be unused.  I need a new attribute of `Type` tMaterial:

```
Type tMaterial
  Name As String
  Crafted As Boolean
  Used As Boolean
  Component() As tComponent
End Type
```

For each material `Used` would have an initial value of False.  As the array was built, any use of the material would be recorded by setting `Used` to True.

Now to design our main two macros.

---

The first step of the array-creating macro is to import the worksheet to a `Variant`.  The first data row is 2.  You can identify the last used row as 14.  The first column is 1.  You can identify the last used column as 12.  A single statement will load this range to a `Variant` which creates an array.  I will import an extra blank column to give:

```
  |   1   |     2  |   3  | 4| 5  | 6| 7     | 8|  9  |10|  11  |12|13| 
--|-------|--------|------|--|----|--|-------|--|-----|--|------|--|--|
 1|Bow    |Crafted |Wood  | 2|Rope| 1|Crystal| 3|Shard| 8|Plumes| 1|  |
 2|Wood   |Crafted |Branch| 2|Leaf| 9|       |  |     |  |      |  |  |
 3|Rope   |Crafted |Web   |10|    |  |       |  |     |  |      |  |  |
 4|Branch |Crafted |Tree  | 1|    |  |       |  |     |  |      |  |  |
 5|Crystal|Resource|      |  |    |  |       |  |     |  |      |  |  |
 6|Plumes |Crafted |Bird  | 1|    |  |       |  |     |  |      |  |  |
 7|Bird   |Resource|      |  |    |  |       |  |     |  |      |  |  |
 8|Web    |Crafted |Spider| 5|    |  |       |  |     |  |      |  |  |
 9|String |Resource|      |  |    |  |       |  |     |  |      |  |  |
10|Shard  |Resource|      |  |    |  |       |  |     |  |      |  |  |
11|Spider |Resource|      |  |    |  |       |  |     |  |      |  |  |
12|Leaf   |Resource|      |  |    |  |       |  |     |  |      |  |  |
13|Tree   |Resource|      |  |    |  |       |  |     |  |      |  |  |
```

I now need to go down each row and check columns 3, 5, 7, 9 and 11.  Any material names must be replaced by the relevant row number.  Since this is a variant array, I can replace a string value with a numeric value.

For example, in element R1C3, I find “Wood”.  I need to look down column 1 for “Wood” which I find in row 2.  I set R1C3 to 2 and R2C13 to “U” to indicate wood is used giving:

```
  |   1   |     2  |   3  | 4| 5  | 6| 7     | 8|  9  |10|  11  |12|13| 
--|-------|--------|------|--|----|--|-------|--|-----|--|------|--|--|
 1|Bow    |Crafted |     2| 2|Rope| 1|Crystal| 3|Shard| 8|Plumes| 1|  |
 2|Wood   |Crafted |Branch| 2|Leaf| 9|       |  |     |  |      |  |U |
 3|Rope   |Crafted |Web   |10|    |  |       |  |     |  |      |  |  |
```

I repeat for R1C5 where I find “Rope”.  I look down column 1 for “Rope” which I find in row 3.  I set R1C5 to 3 and R3C13 to “U” giving:

```
  |   1   |     2  |   3  | 4| 5  | 6| 7     | 8|  9  |10|  11  |12|13| 
--|-------|--------|------|--|----|--|-------|--|-----|--|------|--|--|
 1|Bow    |Crafted |     2| 2|   3| 1|Crystal| 3|Shard| 8|Plumes| 1|  |
 2|Wood   |Crafted |Branch| 2|Leaf| 9|       |  |     |  |      |  |U |
 3|Rope   |Crafted |Web   |10|    |  |       |  |     |  |      |  |U |
```

To transform the original worksheet to the form at the top of this answer (except for column 13), I need:

- An outer loop for each row (1 to 13).
- An inner loop for each of columns 3, 5 and so on containing a material name.
- An inner-inner loop searching the rows for the material name.

I do not need recursion to create this structure.  I could use the modified array on this form but I believe it would make the new-worksheet-creating macro easier to understand if the data was moved to an array of `Type` tMaterial.

---

As I understand it, there is a specific column of a specific worksheet to which you are to output values.  The name of this worksheet, the column letter/number and first row number could be hard-coded into the macro, be defined as constants or be parameters to the macro.  I will ignore the worksheet and column but will make row number a parameter of the macro.

For the first row of the macro you may want:

```
Bow - 1
```

I first read your question to mean you wanted this row suppressed but I am no longer sure if that was the correct interpretation.   No matter; I will explain how this row could be suppressed or made different from the other rows later.

Under this first row you want rows listing the components of Bow:

```
Bow - 1
>Wood – 2
>Rope – 1
»Crystal – 3
»Shard – 8
>Plumes – 1
```

I am using “>” to represent indent because I assume the hyphens following the name are real hyphens.  The 1, 2, 1, 3, 8 and 1 are quantities.

Under the row for Wood, you want rows listing its components but you want the quantities multiplied by 2, the number of Woods:

```
Bow - 1
>Wood – 2
>>Branch – 4
>>Leaf – 18
>Rope – 1
>Crystal – 3
>Shard – 8
>Plumes – 1
```

Branch and Leaf are resources and do not have components but, if they did have components, you would want those components listed under the row for Wood.

This is definitely a requirement for which recursion will be the easiest technique.

The recursive routine (let’s call it `OutMatRow`) will need a number of parameters:

- `Materials`: the array created by the first macro.
- `RowMaterial`: the row within `Materials` for the current material.
- `RowOutput`: the row within the output column.
- `Quantity`: the quantity of the current material.
- `NumIndents`: the number of indents for the current material.

I say “parameters” but `Materials` could be a global variable since `OutMatRow` does not change this array.  `RowOutput` could also be a global because the source variable is updated each time a row is output.  `RowMaterial`, `Quantity` and `NumIndents` MUST be parameters because each call needs its own values for these parameters.

The control routine will call `OutMatRow` for each unused material.  With your demonstration data the only unused material is Bow so the call will be:

```
Call OutMatRow(Materials, 2, X, 1, 0)
```

where X represents the number of the first output row.

There will be little code in `OutMatRow`.

- The row for the material must be output.  `NumIndents`, `Materials(RowMaterial).Name` and `Quantity` give the values for this row.  You can have a different format or suppress output when `NumIndents = 0` if you want.
- `RowOutput` must be stepped ready for the next output row.
- For each component of a crafted material, the routine will call itself so:

  ```
  Call OutMatRow(Materials, _
                 Materials(RowMaterial).Component(N).RowMaterial, _
                 RowOutput, _
                 Quantity * _
                     Materials(RowMaterial).Component(N).Quantity, _
                 NumIndents + 1)
  ```

If you are not familiar with recursive routines, it is a little difficult to understand the sequence in which the calls of `OutMatRow` occur:

- The control macro calls `OutMatRow`for Bow.
- `OutMatRow` outputs the row for Bow and calls itself for Bow’s first component which is Wood.
- `OutMatRow` outputs the row for Wood and calls itself for Wood’s first component which is Branch.
- `OutMatRow` outputs the row for Branch.  Branch has no components so the routine returns to its caller.
- `OutMatRow` calls itself for Wood’s second component which is Leaf.
- `OutMatRow` outputs the row for Leaf.  Leaf has no components so the routine returns to its caller.
- Wood has no more components so the routine returns to its caller.
- `OutMatRow` calls itself for Bow’s second component which is Rope.
- And so on.

This will be difficult to get your head around.  Try with the explanation I have given.  If you are still struggling come back with questions and I will attempt a different explanation.

Comment: Very helpful, maybe I am too "stuck" with what I know. To answer your questions: "...“bow” is the only material that is not a component ...How will you know which elements of the array relate to which row in the worksheet?" On another worksheet, there is Bow, but Bow is also in the data, I was thinking about passing "Bow" to the data sheet for the array creation. How long did you spend writing ReDimPreserve? Not long, I modified code I found online, "If you return to these macros in six or twelve months which of these two approaches will be easier to understand?" I agree with you on this one.

Comment: For additional precision, there will be several components that will create that array, I used Bow in the example, but the goal is to call the array function with a component and get all the listed materials as I specified on my Excel output. Gun could also be in the data, and the materials could be new ones, or some could be used again. The goal was to recreate the array whenever a new component would be called in the function. Example: Worksheet 1: Bow - then we list the materials by checking the "data sheet", on another line Gun - then we list the materials using the "data sheet" again.

Comment: @DyrFenrir. I do not know how to interpret your comments. My array-creating macro would convert all the data within the worksheet to an easily processable form regardless of how many materials like Bow or Gun are present. My new-worksheet-creating macro outputs all the components of any single material. It would be the control routine that would decide which material or materials were to be output. My macros meets my understanding of your requirement although not in the way you were attempting because I do not know how to get you proposed array structure to meet your requirement.

Comment: I think you understood exactly what I needed, I added the additional precision because I wanted to make sure I explained everything correctly. Indeed, your solution seems to cover everything and I will need some time to process it completely and try and code it correctly. I'll keep this post updated along the way.

Comment: @DyrFenrir.  If you need to ask questions about implementation, do not hesitate.  I have told you what to do and shown you some syntax but you may find it difficult to discover how to achieve some effects.

Comment: I further updated my original post to add the new code I created with all the helpful tips you provided (it made it so much easier), although I understand the "Used" attribute, I was not able to find how to incorporate it. Also, I still have to figure out how to handle the output (you provided the recursive call, I just need to code the sub). I will get on that as soon as possible.

Comment: I am trying to access the type content to pass it to another sub but I keep getting: "Only user-defined types defined in public object modules can be coerced to or from a variant or passed to late-bound functions" Am I missing something? I tried to put all the code in a module but i still get the same result, I declared almost everything as "Public" as well.

Comment: Sorry if you got several notifications about the previous comment, I had an issue with my browser.

Comment: @DyrFenrir.  Why are you coercing a user type to a Variant?  I suspect the parameters for the sub are not typed.  Untyped variables and parameters are given a default type of Variant.  See the code in my new answer where  pass Materials as a parameter.